# EF Core Query Performance

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-3.1

I have a query that loads extremely slowly. I think something is very wrong with it, but i dont understand why.
In my application i have an entity KeyText:

```
public class KeyText
    int Id
    Group Group
    string Text
```

Most other entities have several of these keytexts. Its just a simple way of filling comboboxes.
So if i load via ef core like this: (Everything in the ThenInclude lambda is a KeyText)

```
context.Companies
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.AdressType);
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.CityType);
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.AnotherKeyText);
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.DifferentKeyText);
```

This can, in the real app, load up to 20 seconds for a ridicolously low
amount of data. I'm talking like 5 entries in 5 collections.

However if i load like this:

```
var companies = context.Companies;
companies.adresses = context.Adresses
                        Include(a => a.AdressType)
                        Include(a => a.CityType)
                        Include(a => a.AnotherKeyText)
                        Include(a => a.DifferentKeyText);
```

It loads instantly. Why is this? Is the first query that wrong?

Comment: See [Significant Query Slowdown When Using Multiple Joins Due To Changes In 3.0 #18022](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18022) (issue), [Relational split query mode for collection includes #20892](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20892) (actual work) and [suggested workaround by EF Core team member](https://gist.github.com/smitpatel/d4cb3619e5b33e8d9ea24d3f2a88333a)

Answer (score 1):

Let assume you have 5 companies, each one has 5 Addresses:

```
context.Companies
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.AdressType);
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.CityType);
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.AnotherKeyText);
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.DifferentKeyText);
```

This code generates 5*5=25 left join behalf of Sql each one composed of 3 join (Companies * Adresses * types)

---

```
var companies = context.Companies;
companies.adresses = context.Adresses
    .Include(a => a.AdressType)
    .Include(a => a.CityType)
    .Include(a => a.AnotherKeyText)
    .Include(a => a.DifferentKeyText);
```

This code generates 5 left join behalf of Sql each one composed of 2 join (Adresses * types)

So it's obvious that first approach damages your performance significantly.

Anyway try to not use `Include` as far as you can. Instead load minimum amount of data that you need and with `Join` and `Select` expressions.

Comment: What you are explaining is implementation detail (inefficiency introduced by EF Core 3.0 new query processing pipeline). They shouldn't provide such methods (`Include` / `ThenInclude`) if they cannot process them efficiently. There is nothing wrong with OP query. "Avoid using valid public API" doesn't sound good.

Comment: @IvanStoev In fact `Include` has its advantages only IF it uses in correct situations and this achieved by some experience in this area. Generally Linq queries has many tricks to work optimize and you can't use them blindly. My advice here is valid until he understand all behinds and use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to speed up your query in **EF** is using [`.AsNoTracking()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)

```cs
var companies = context.Companies.AsNoTracking();
companies.adresses = context.Adresses.AsNoTracking()
                        .Include(a => a.AdressType)
                        .Include(a => a.CityType)
                        .Include(a => a.AnotherKeyText)
                        .Include(a => a.DifferentKeyText)
```

```cs
context.Companies.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.AdressType);
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.CityType);
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.AnotherKeyText);
    .Include(c => c.Adresses).ThenInclude(a => a.DifferentKeyText);
```

> No tracking queries are useful when the results are used in a read-only scenario. They're quicker to execute because there's no need to set up the change tracking information. If you don't need to update the entities retrieved from the database, then a no-tracking query should be used. You can swap an individual query to be no-tracking

By default, queries that return entity types are tracking. Which means you can make changes to those entity instances and have those changes persisted by `SaveChanges()`.

When you load data from Database by default all records has been tracked by `ChangeTracker` and this will cause a slight drop in speed and memory allocation.

[image]